# Getting a NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im getting this error:

Showing /Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/imright/app/views/users/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #4):

```
4: <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

5:   <div class="field">
6:     <%= f.label :name %><br />
7:     <%= f.text_field :name %>
```

what do i change to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@user` does not exist then (Look in the error because it is saying that it is a NilClass).

You either want to do:

```
form_for(User.new) do |f|
```

or set `@user` in the controller;

```
class UsersController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  new
end
```

I suggest the latter because it's a rule of thumb for MVC to not put model calls in your views.

Answer (score 1):

try to view page
<%= form_for @user, :url=> {:action =>"create"} do |f| %>
in controller
def new
      @user = User.new
    end

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

           if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Registration successful."
           redirect_to(:controller =>"user_sessions", :action =>"new")
     else
            render :action => 'new'
     end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

That indicates that @user is nil. Perhaps you changed the variable name from @user to something else in your controller and forgot to change it in your view? Maybe this view is being rendered in the create or update action after an error, and the variable is called something besides @user in those actions?